# How to count distinct instances of two columns when one column is a date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, concatenation, countif

I have a table like this:

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Ann | 2/1/2024 |
| Bob | 3/3/2024 |
| Ann | 2/1/2024 |
| Bob | 3/5/2024 |

I want to be able to tell what unique combinations of the two columns there are and if there are any repeats.

My method was to join the fields in a new field using =CONCAT(A2,TEXT(B2,"mm/dd/yyyy"):

| Name | Date | combined |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ann | 2/1/2024 | Ann2/1/2024 |
| Bob | 3/3/2024 | Bob3/3/2024 |
| Ann | 2/1/2024 | Ann2/1/2024 |
| Bob | 3/5/2024 | Bob3/5/2024 |

I then coped/pasted this combined column as value, so the formulas don't affect any future functions.

Then, I created a new column that should count the instances that each item occurs in column c =COUNTIF(C:C,C2):

| Name | Date | combined_pastedasvalues | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ann | 2/1/2024 | Ann2/1/2024 | 2 |
| Bob | 3/3/2024 | Bob3/3/2024 | 1 |
| Ann | 2/1/2024 | Ann2/1/2024 | 2 |
| Bob | 3/5/2024 | Bob3/5/2024 | 2 |

However, when I do this, it looks like the count isn't working properly (see the fourth row, it should only have a count of 1 when it's showing 2), and there are items returned with 12 instances of occurring, but when I go to check, it's the only instance in the dataset.

Any advice here on how to make this work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have posted two samples of data and that are different. Why cant you post few more samples, to see how your formula is not working? also when concatenating we usually suggest in using a delimiter, you have not used any

Comment: I also tried concatenating columns A and B without changing the dates to text, and I get the same results (the date is transformed to numbers)

Comment: Also why not simple use of `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)` shouldn't this work for your query

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one can use the following with intermediate columns to accomplish the desired output:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=A2:A5&"|"&TEXT(B2:B5,"m/d/e")
```

---

While in <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=COUNTIF(C2#,C2)
```

---

Or, use the following with `MMULT()`

[image]

---

```
=LET(x,A2:A5& "|"&TEXT(B2:B5,"m/d/e"), MMULT(N(x=TOROW(x)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(x))^0))
```

---

Using `ETA LAMBDA` it will be shorter as well:

[image]

---

```
=LET(x,A2:A5& "|"&TEXT(B2:B5,"m/d/e"), BYROW(N(x=TOROW(x)),SUM))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Table` (named `Table1`) and structured references:

```
=SUM(
    --(
        CONCAT(Table1[@[Name]:[Date]]) =
            BYROW(
                Table1[[Name]:[Date]],
                LAMBDA(arr, CONCAT(arr))
            )
    )
)
```

[image]

Some advantages of using a Table:

- The formulas will auto-populate as you add/delete rows
- No references in the formula will also adjust to the size of the table.